# How to transfer/copy Notes from one iDevice to another without using restore method?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, icloud, notes.app

I tried using iCloud account.  But it did not seem to work.  basically, I signed into iCloud on both iDevices with same Apple ID.  And making sure Notes was set to on.  Newly created notes will show up on both devices.  But I also need the current local previously created notes to sync as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

With iOS 9:

Open the Folder containing the Notes you want to move.

Click the Edit button. It is faint. You might not see it right away.

You will see a column of selection circles ⭕️ appear, and also the words Delete All and Move All.

Tap the circles for your target Notes, then Move To ..., and the destination.

All done.

Comment: That's only for the one in the iCloud Notes section, for ones on Local Notes, does not give the option to "move all".

Answer (score 3):

As it turned out, Apple does not provide an option to auto sync/copy previously created notes for Notes app to iCloud in order to sync to other iDevice.  From this [doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4191?viewlocale=en_US):

"In Notes on your iOS device or Mac, verify that your notes are not stored in a local folder. Example: On My iPhone or On My Mac. If you have notes in these folders, you will need to copy or transfer them to iCloud or IMAP to sync with your other devices."

Well you will need to literately do what what doc said: copy/paste one note at a time to iCloud.  If you had previously create notes and once you signed in iCloud account, the Notes app will show two accounts: "On My iPhone (or iPad)" and "iCloud".  So you just need to do it copy and paste one note at a time the old passion way.  This is no fun.

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple, try Airdrop, open the notes on iphone from which you wish to transfer it, tap on Share icon, tap "AirDrop", and simultaneously enable "AirDrop" from other iphone, choose "Everyone" ,and you are done with it.
Only drawback is that we have transfer notes one by one.

Comment: This. 
If the destination device has iCloud account as default under Settings -> Notes, the notes will be stored in iCloud and available on all devices. In the same way, using two iOS devices, it's possible to transfer notes from other cloud accounts e.g. Google.
One by one, yes, but arguably better than copy-paste.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides a web interface, so you can log in to https://icloud.com and see which notes are syncing.

Then once you are logged in, go to one of the devices and sign out and back in with the same Apple ID. Check that the date is correct on the device before signing back in. At that point, go to the settings app and ensure notes are synced for iCloud. Also, update your iOS device unless you have a very good reason to not run the latest version of iOS on each device.

Once you have notes syncing from the web to the first device (and back) then you can repeat the same steps with the second device.

iCloud should sync notes to multiple iOS devices as long as you are using the same exact account and have signed in correctly. I've seen a wrong date cause delays or no syncing since the code has to know which device has the last version of each note to work.

Comment: In my iPad Notes app, it shows two Accounts: "On My iPad" and "iCloud".  The notes in iCloud account sync correctly.  But I also need to copy/sync the one is "On My iPad".  According to Apple doc, I need to copy the local notes to iCloud.  But how to do that?

Comment: Here is the document from Apple to tell you to copy local notes to iCloud.  But it did not tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I used AirDrop to transfer the Notes (one at a time).  The source device had two Notes accounts, one of which was syncing and one local only.  The destination device had only one Notes account, which was syncing.  I transferred each Note using AirDrop from the source device local account to the destination device single account.  After syncing, the Notes appeared on the source device's synced account.

Answer (score 1):

- iOS9.x
- open notes
- click on the right side "refresh" in the section ICLOUD
- click next. let iOS9 upgrades your notes
- now you can move your local notes to iCloud